# Use the result of one query to create a new select statement using SQL only

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the impression that the following is not possible using SQL but wanted to ask here before dismissing it entirely.

In a very poorly designed DB I have to use, one table holds as values the field names of another table. Simplified, the table, let's call it ColumnTable, looks like this:

```
ID          ColumnName
------      -----------
23          Column_1
24          Column_2
```

The other table, let's call it ContentTable, accordingly, looks as follows:

```
ID          Column_1          Column_2
------      -----------       ----------
101         Somecontent1       Somecontent3
102         Somecontent2       Somecontent4
```

As you can see, there are no foreign keys I can use, the whole DB is an absolute nightmare. Redesigning the DB to bring it in a normal form is out of the questions since a closed source application depends on the DB having exactly this layout. The layout being more one of a registry than of a relational DB.

Anyway, as you have already guessed, to query the content from the ContentTable, one first needs to get the respective field name. I am quite certain that the application does this in two steps: It first queries the name of the field, then it uses the result of this query to create a new query string to query the content.

To make an example, we know that we wish to query the row with the ID 101 in the ContentTable but we don't know which column. But we know that we can find the name of the column in the row with the ID 23 of the ColumnTable. I assume the application does this as follows.

```
int fieldsID = 23
int contentID = 101
string columnName
string neededResult

columnName = SQLQuery("SELECT ColumnName FROM ColumnTable WHERE ID =" + fieldsID)
echo columnName //Will return Column_1

neededResult = SQLQuery("SELECT " + columnName + "FROM ContentTable")
echo neededResult //Will return Somecontent1
```

Is there any way to do this using only SQL?

`SELECT (SELECT ColumnName FROM ColumnTable WHERE ID = 1) FROM ContentTable` (to receive the desired select statement `SELECT Column_1 FROM ContentTable WHERE ID = 1`) obviously won't work, since the nested SELECT statement just creates a new field with the query result for content.

As mentioned, doing this from code is no problem but it's inefficient. Is there a way to do this in SQL? While this question is relevant for SQL in general, this specific DB is in MSSQL so if there is some trick to do this efficiently in T-SQL, for example using a function or SPROC, I'll appreciate the advice.

Comment: Please show us the result that you would expect.

Comment: The expected result is basically a new select statement. I clarified how this new statement should look like.

Comment: I don't think you have clarified. Are you simply wanting a statement that has the names of the columns replaced with the proper ones?

Comment: But the column is called `Column_1` in both the columns table and the content table; so how do you *not* know what the name is.

Comment: @Larnu I may have not been clear enough in my original question so I made some substantial edits. Please let me know if this is clearer now.

Comment: I've already added an answer to what I *think* you're after; but it's the design that *really* needs fixing I'm afraid.

Comment: FYI, you should *really* learn to parametrise your statements. Stuff like `SQLQuery("SELECT ColumnName FROM ColumnTable WHERE ID =" + fieldsID)` is **very** open to SQL injection.

Comment: That's just pseudo code of what I assume the closed source application looks like, it's not how I would write it myself. But thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a blind guess, but perhaps this is what you are after. If it *is* though, then you *really* need to fix the design; as you can see there are so many problems with ones like this.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ColumnTable (ID int,
                              ColumnName sysname); --Tables don't have "fields" that have columns and rows

CREATE TABLE dbo.ContentTable (ID int,
                               Column_1 varchar(50),
                               Column_2 varchar(50));

GO

INSERT INTO dbo.ColumnTable (ID, ColumnName)
VALUES(1,'Column_1'),
      (2,'Column_2');

INSERT INTO dbo.ContentTable (ID, Column_1, Column_2)
VALUES (1,'Somecontent1','Somecontent3'),
       (2,'Somecontent2','Somecontent4');

GO

DECLARE @ColumnID int = 1,
        @ContentID int = 1;

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName) + @CRLF +
              N'FROM dbo.ContentTable' + @CRLF +
              N'WHERE ID = @ContentID;'
FROM dbo.ColumnTable
WHERE ID = @ColumnID;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@ContentID int', @ContentID;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.ColumnTable;
DROP TABLE dbo.ContentTable;
```

Comment: I changed your ID's to reflect the ones in my question. I think there is just one thing you may want to correct, the ID's of the rows in the ColumnTable and in the ContenTable are not the same. As mentioned, there is no foreign key between these tables.

Comment: So how do you relate the rows? The edit you suggested *breaks* this; and if your sample data wasn't representative then it doesn't help. If there is no relationship, there is nothing to relate the data, and nothing to get what you want. ID `23` and ID `101` must relate *somehow*, as they are related to what you want.

Comment: As mentioned, I do know the ID's I'm looking for. I do know that I need to look for the column name in the ColumnTable with row ID 23, and I do know that I need to look in the ContentTable with row ID 101. Just the column name I need to retrieve as a string from ColumnTable, first. I am under the impression that your code might work with some changes, I'm currently testing this... but as you correctly say, it's not a relational design in any sense of the expression.

Comment: I can confirm that this works. This way, I can shift the code from my application to the server. It's still not ideal but I don't think there is a better solution. If the main application were mine, I'd do a full redesign of the DB but that's not an option. Thanks @Larnu.

Comment: P.S. Please change the ID's to reflect the ones in my original question, other people reading this will otherwise be confused.